# Not displaying correctly transpose of matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

It works fine for quadratic matrix (2x2 or 3x3) but for 2x3 or 3x2 it doesn't display correctly!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,j,k,c1,c2,l1,l2;
int m1[10][10],m2[10][10],transposta[10][10],multiplicacao[10][10];

printf("\nDigite o numero de linhas e colunas na primeira matriz\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&l1,&c1);
        printf("\nDigite os elementos da matriz:\n");
        for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&m1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            {
                transposta[j][i] = m1[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("\nA matriz transposta e:\n");
        for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
                printf("%d\t",transposta[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
```

If I put elements {1,2,3,4,5,6} in a 2x3 matrix, it displays like this:

1 4 1

2 5 0

However the correct way would be:

1 4

2 5

3 6

What is wrong with the code and why it doesn't work when the number of rows is different than columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct in your code, just change

```
for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
                printf("%d\t",transposta[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
```

by

```
for(i=0;i<c1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<l1;j++)
                printf("%d\t",transposta[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
```

for printing purpose, you have to take care of c1 and l1

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10][10], transpose[10][10], r, c, i, j;
    printf("Enter rows and columns of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    // Storing elements of the matrix
    printf("\nEnter elements of matrix:\n");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter element a%d%d: ",i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }

    // Displaying the matrix a[][] */
    printf("\nEntered Matrix: \n");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", a[i][j]);
            if (j == c-1)
                printf("\n\n");
        }

    // Finding the transpose of matrix a
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            transpose[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }

    // Displaying the transpose of matrix a
    printf("\nTranspose of Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
        for(j=0; j<r; j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ",transpose[i][j]);
            if(j==r-1)
                printf("\n\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your transpose logic is not correct. The correct for loop would be

```
    // note use c1 here not l1
    for(i=0;i<c1;i++)
    {
        //note use l1 here not c1
        for(j=0;j<l1;j++)
        {
            //  indexing of m1 is changed
            transposta[i][j] = m1[j][i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nA matriz transposta e:\n");
    // same here
    for(i=0;i<c1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<l1;j++)
            printf("%d\t",transposta[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

When you transpose, rows become columns and columns become rows, so you need to change for loop indexes as per that.